# El valor tomado por getline es siempre distinto a el de una comprobacion

Tags: c++, archivo, csv

Estoy trabajando con un bucle que pasa por todos los datos de un fichero .csv el cual contiene una *M* o una *F* en la segunda posicion. para obtener esos datos estoy haciendo `getline(f, gender, ',')` que en efecto acaba conteniendo uno de los dos valores posibles pero a la hora de compararlos con *"M"* o *"F"* como letras para llevar un conteo de el numero de veces que aparecen estos nunca se incrementan:

```
getline (f, gender, ',');
    cout << gender << endl;
    if (gender == "F"){
        female++;
    }
    else{ 
        males++; 
    }
```

Ambas variables han sido declaradas anteriormente como `int` y se realizan los `cout`de la variable *gender* como se espera pero los valores no son incrementados.

Pienso que puede ser porque `getline` no solo obtiene el valor de la letra pero algo mas pero por mas que pienso y pruebo y compruebo partes del codigo no consigo encontrar el error. Tambien probe a en vez de poner *"F"* como variable a asignarsela a un string como *gender* para que se comparasen variables del mismo tipo pero aun asi no realiza el recuento.

Tras la ejecucion obtengo que solo hay un *M* y no hay *F* por lo que no se si se esta ejecutando correctamente a pesar de que si que se imprimen todos los datos del fichero con las ejecucion de los 3 `cout` correcpondientes.
Tras eliminar el primer cout del primer elemento no se imprime nada del archivo. ¿Significa que el unico dato que se esta imprimiendo es el 1º y que este almacena todo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de porque el valor tomado por `getline` y el de la comprobacion no son iguales?

Answer (score 0):

Tras varias pruebas he acabado extrayendo toda la linea que al final siempre son numeros con una *F* o *M* para el genero y usando `find` para ver si contenia el caracter lo cual ha resuelto completamente el problema:

```
string female = "F";
string line;
while (getline (f, line, '\n')){        
        if (line.find(female) != std::string::npos) {
            females++;
        }
        else {
            males++;
        }
}
```